# Using jq to count

Tags: json, count, conditional-statements, jq

Using jq-1.5 if I have a file of JSON that looks like

```
[{... ,"sapm_score":40.776, ...} {..., "spam_score":17.376, ...} ...]
```

How would I get a count of the ones where `sapm_score > 40`?

Thanks,
Dan

Update:

I looked at the input file and the format is actually

```
{... ,"sapm_score":40.776, ...}
{..., "spam_score":17.376, ...}
...
```

Does this change how one needs to count?

Comment: If the input is a newline delimited sequence of objects instead of an array  the solutions here can use `inputs` instead of `.[]` if jq is passed the `-n` flag.

Comment: Given that `spam_score` makes sense is `sapm_score` correct or a typo?  If it's correct do you need normalization as [peak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997358/peak) suggested?  If it's just a typo would you mind correcting the information in your question?

Answer (score 10):

[UPDATE: If the input is not an array, see the last section below.]

#### `count/1`

I'd recommend defining a `count` filter (and maybe putting it in your ~/.jq), perhaps as follows:

```
 def count(s): reduce s as $_ (0;.+1);
```

With this, assuming the input is an array, you'd write:

```
 count(.[] | select(.sapm_score > 40))
```

or slightly more efficiently:

```
 count(.[] | (.sapm_score > 40) // empty)
```

This approach (counting items in a stream) is usually preferable to using `length` as it avoids the costs associated with constructing an array.

#### `count/2`

Here's another definition of `count` that you might like to use (and perhaps add to ~/.jq as well):

```
def count(stream; cond): count(stream | cond // empty);
```

This counts the elements of the stream for which `cond` is neither `false` nor `null`.

Now, assuming the input consists of an array, you can simply write:

```
count(.[]; .sapm_score > 40)
```

#### "sapm_score" vs "spam_score"

If the point is that you want to normalize "sapm_score" to "spam_score", then (for example) you could use `count/2` as defined above, like so:

```
 count(.[]; .spam_score > 40 or .sapm_score > 40)
```

This assumes all the items in the array are JSON objects. If that is not the case, then you might want to try adding "?" after the key names:

```
count(.[]; .spam_score? > 40 or .sapm_score? > 40)
```

Of course all the above assumes the input is valid JSON. If that is not the case, then please see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json

#### If the input is a stream of JSON objects ...

The revised question indicates the input consists of a stream of JSON objects (whereas originally the input was said to be an array of JSON objects).  If the input consists of a stream of JSON objects, then the above solutions can easily be adapted, depending on the version of jq that you have.  If your version of jq has `inputs` then (2) is recommended.

(1) All versions: use the `-s` command-line option.

(2) If your jq has `inputs`: use the `-n` command line option, and change `.[]` above to `inputs`, e.g.

```
count(inputs; .spam_score? > 40 or .sapm_score? > 40)
```

Comment: Actually tried that before posting.  Get 'jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "spam_score"' for every line in the file.

Comment: @DanEhrlich - Does the update address your question satisfactorily?

Answer (score 6):

Filter the items that satisfy the condition then get the length.

```
map(select(.sapm_score > 40)) | length
```

Answer (score 3):

```bash
cat input.json | jq -c '. | select(.sapm_score > 40)' | wc -l
```

should do it.

The `-c` option prints a one-liner compact json representation of each match, and we count the number of lines jq prints.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
reduce .[] as $s(0; if $s.spam_score > 40 then .+1 else . end)
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/k747PBLh4T)

If instead of an array the input is a sequence of newline delimited objects [(jsonlines)](http://jsonlines.org/examples/)

```
reduce inputs as $s(0; if $s.spam_score > 40 then .+1 else . end)
```

will work if jq is invoked with the `-n` flag.  Here is an example:

```
$ cat data.json
{ "spam_score":40.776 }
{ "spam_score":17.376 }

$ jq -Mn 'reduce inputs as $s(0; if $s.spam_score > 40 then .+1 else . end)' data.json
1
```

[Try it online at tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsIwFAX3nuJRhCriJ8ViQEt3uhOPIDH50paa1v50JZ49FhcK7oaBgbkaqaI1AaUzwVAjnUdRHM7H2ROJ9OZ@EdsNnOxyRVpv8fr3mabNx09NbB5YnzzSgd1oGbXvxyAwgrks1B71bQL61SiRK4SKPWiVgVthENi7ZYrvToxv)